# Oracle SQL: How to add total column to results set?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following query:

```
WITH
  curr AS ( 
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM   table1  
    WHERE column1 LIKE 'A%'
    AND column2 = TRUNC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
  ),
  hist AS (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM   table2 
    WHERE column1 LIKE 'A%'
    AND column2 = TRUNC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
  )
SELECT (curr+hist) FROM dual;
```

Now this query doesn't work because `curr` and `hist` are invalid identifiers, but I would like to combine the two results into a total and return that. How could this be done?

Comment: `UNION` those two selects and calculate the `SUM` of the resulting column values. The CTE (`WITH` clause) is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to reference the two CTE's in your `SELECT`.  Something like

```
WITH
  curr AS ( 
    SELECT COUNT(*) cnt
    FROM   table1  
    WHERE column1 LIKE 'A%'
    AND column2 = TRUNC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
  ),
  hist AS (
    SELECT COUNT(*) cnt
    FROM   table2 
    WHERE column1 LIKE 'A%'
    AND column2 = TRUNC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
  )
SELECT curr.cnt + hist.cnt
  FROM curr
       CROSS JOIN hist
```

would work.  So would

```
WITH
  curr AS ( 
    SELECT COUNT(*) cnt
    FROM   table1  
    WHERE column1 LIKE 'A%'
    AND column2 = TRUNC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
  ),
  hist AS (
    SELECT COUNT(*) cnt
    FROM   table2 
    WHERE column1 LIKE 'A%'
    AND column2 = TRUNC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
  )
SELECT SUM(cnt)
  FROM (SELECT curr.cnt FROM curr
        UNION ALL
        SELECT hist.cnt FROM hist)
```